# Does readLine() put extra char to resulting string?

Tags: android, string, sqlite, readline

here is code to read from file :

```
        String line, Matn;
    line = br.readLine();
    Matn = "s"+line.substring(2);
    while (true){
        line = br.readLine();
        if (line==null) break;
        Matn += " "+line;
    }
```

first line result is this

```
select '10','استان تهران' UNION
```

Here there is a char in position 0 of first line read before select statment, that is not seen but in "marking condition : shify down left + right arrow" you can feel that there is a non space char.
Then using this string as feed for SQL statement cause to fail.
Am I making a mistake or it is true?
To solve this I trimed 2 positions and added lost "s", so it work fine.
your help is welcome.

Comment: Even in this test you can feel the hiden char.... !!!!

Comment: Are you reading from a file? Maybe it is UTF-8 BOM.

Comment: yepp, might well be the BOM

Comment: UTF-8 BOM: One bad idea going viral.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes for UTF-8 compatiblity it add `"\u200F"` to start of file.
It is possible to do `.replace("\u200F","")`, or using `substring(1, text.length()-1)` jump over it.

Comment: If you've found the answer by yourself, accept it so people can use it for future references. :)